# How to show $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a maximal subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

How to show that $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a maximal subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$?

By definition, $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a maximal subgroup means there are no other proper subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ that contain $U_n(\mathbb{C})$.

So let $G$ be a proper subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $G \supset U_n(\mathbb{C})$. And I want to show that $G \subset U_n(\mathbb{C})$, hence $G = U_n(\mathbb{C})$. But I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ denotes unitary $n \times n$-matrices, this is not true in general. The group of matrices with determinant of absolute value 1 is a proper subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ which properly contains $U_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Isn't $U_n(\mathbb{C})=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{C}) \mid A^tA=I\}$ So For any $A\in U_n(\mathbb{C})$, $\mid \det(A)\mid = 1$? So the subgroup that you propose is actually $U_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @SamC, yes, that shows that $U_n$ is contained in the group of matrices with determinant of absolute value 1. However, there are plenty of matrices with determinant 1 which are not unitary.

Comment: So you suggesting $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is not a maximal subgroup? Or I need to show if $\mid \det(A)\mid =1$ than $A \in U_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: I wrote "this is not true in general", so yes, I am suggesting that it is not a maximal subgroup.

Comment: But in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group also some other book that I read they say that $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: Yes, but your question did not involve the word "compact".

Comment: Does the word compact play an important role here?

Comment: Please read a little more about the subject, this comment section is not meant to teach mathematics... (and yes, the word "compact" is important.)